# How can I have a function perform after a Datetime in my DB is met?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datetime

I'm creating an auction site where users can bid on items. I want to create a script that sends an email to the winner of an auction item once the datetime in the end_auction column has been reached.

I'm not sure how to go about doing this, since PHP only runs when the page is loaded and then stops. Also, I want it to send an email to the winner once the auction is over even when nobody is looking at any page.

So i guess I need some sort of functionality that will constantly check my server to see if the end_auction DateTime of an event has been met and then send them an email using the Mail function if it has.

What programming languages would I need? What approach could I use to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your logic in php and schedule your php script to run using [cron](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html).

Comment: This worked Great! I found a great tutorial that explains how to set up a cron job here: http://www.upstartblogger.com/how-to-create-a-cron-job-in-cpanel and http://www.2serveu.net/cpanel-tutorials/standardcron.html

Answer (score 3):

A dedicated program or script could handle this.  It need not have a GUI, since its operations are:

```
list all users with closed auctions who have not been notified
for each user in the list
    email notification
    if no error, mark user notified
```

Choose your poison.  PHP can do this outside a webserver, as can Perl, Python, Java, etc., etc.

Comment: it would add this script under the crontab (linux), or a as scheduled task/service (windows).